# Charge Pump - pre-existing ICs?

Tags: high-voltage, charge-pump

I would like to generate a biasing voltage of around ~300-500V. The load is small, less than 1mA (i.e., ~1W power transfer). Input is 30V DC, so I need a 10x voltage amplification. Normally, given I don't need much efficiency nor do I care about ripple too much, I'd go for a series of voltage doublers built with discrete components.

But I'm a lazy engineer and I like simpler, smaller solutions that can be implemented quickly. As such, I'm looking to see if there's a component that can do this pumping for me. A dig through the electronics retailers shows that such components exist - but are limited in their output voltage to about 12V or so - presumably for the more usual requirement of biasing a communications line or something. The best I have found is this [Linear 3482](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3482fa.pdf) or [8331](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/8331fa.pdf), but these top out at 90/100V, and, from their relatively high transfer powers and conventional regulator topologies, seem to be the "wrong kind" of pump for me.

Part of me thinks that what I'm looking for is too specialised, and ICs that output this kind of voltage don't exist (if nothing else, because the separation of their pins would need to start being quite large!). This part of me says that the best I can hope for is a driver IC, to control a discretely-implemented Dickerson or Bootstrap CP.

But the other part of me says that this isn't an usual thing - camera flashes, for example, routinely require biasing this high (or used to!) - and so commercial solutions should exist. This part of me thinks I'm looking in the wrong places or using the wrong keywords for my sought-after part.

**Do you know of any integrated charge pump or voltage regulators that can output ≥300V biasing voltages?**

Comment: Camera flases use similar circuits to what crj11 has put in his answer.

Comment: Apologies for the off-topic question. Still learning the standard here! If I were to edit it to ask what the *type* of part that does this is (rather than requesting specific parts) it would be more timeless and more likely to help other people in the same situation in the future. Would such a change be suitable/useful?

Answer (score 1):

The Analog Devices (via Linear Tech) [LTC3751](http://www.analog.com/en/products/power-management/switching-regulators/flyback-forward-isolated-controllers/lt3751.html#product-overview) should work for you.

From the product page:

> The LT3751 is a high input voltage capable flyback controller designed to rapidly charge a large capacitor to a user-adjustable high target voltage set by the transformer turns ratio and three external resistors. Optionally, a feedback pin can be used to provide a low noise high voltage regulated output.

If you don't need the voltage regulation, you can use the [LT3750](http://www.analog.com/en/products/power-management/switching-regulators/flyback-forward-isolated-controllers/lt3750.html#product-overview).

[image]

Comment: Yes! That's almost exactly what I was looking for. Moreover, taking the "Capacitor Charger" description means I have found some other similar parts for me to look through. Thanks muchly, @crj11